# General position : Why is a picewise linear embedding necessary?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, geometric-topology, transversality

I am currently studying a little bit of general position and transversality theory and I was told that it is necessary to consider at least a picewise linear embedding of two submanifolds to be able to state a General Position Theorem for Embeddings such as this one found in: Rourke, Sanderson, *Introduction to piecewise linear topology*:

> **Theorem** Let $ Q^q, P_0\subset P^p$ be closed subpolyhedra of the unbounded manifold $M^m$ with $cl(P-P_0)$ compact. Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Then there is an $\epsilon$-isotopy of $M$ with compact support, fixed on $P_0$ and finishing with $h:M\rightarrow M$ such that $$dim(h(P-P_0)\cap Q) \leq p+q-m$$
>   *Addendum* If $p+q=m$ then we can also arrange that $h(P-P_0)$ meets Q transversely.

Now what could happen if $P$ or $Q$ weren't even polyhedra? What kind of ugly thing could happen with a topological embedding so that no general position is possible? If possible I would need some references.

Thank's a lot!

Comment: Embeddings of the Cantor set are very weird beasts, there's no "transversality theorem" for them that I am aware of.

Comment: Thank you. I am a little bit confused with Cantor sets: -What kind of embedding in the real line are available for Cantor sets? I mean, How can a Cantor set can be considered as a submanifold of $\mathbb R$? - Is it necessary to consider the Hausdorff dimension of the Cantor set? If yes, how is it compatible with its dimension as submanifold?

Comment: The Cantor set cannot be considered as a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}$. So, my comment was a hint that your question is missing some additional conditions that you may need to impose on $P$ and $Q$, because for some kinds of topological spaces there is no hope for a general position theorem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should at least restrict to the category of topological manifolds (and topological submanifolds). The there is indeed a notion of transversality and a general position theorem, but you can easily spend a year trying to understand the precise statement (e.g. what is a *normal microbundle*?). The result is mostly due to Rob Kirby and Larry Siebenmann (under some dimension assumption) and to Frank Quinn in full generality. See [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183554528) and references therein. (Just keep in mind that the book reference [4] there is basically unreadable unless your speciality is higher-dimensional topology.)

Comment: Thank you for this precise answer. Then a good reason for choosing to work in the PL category rather than Topological or Smooth would be that a Transversality/General Position Theorem is much cheaper ?

Comment: @user448839: Right.